# How to transform images with additional distortion?

Tags: image-processing

I want to transform an image area (e.g. a piece of paper with text) from an arbitrary, distorted view to a predefined view (e.g. top down). So basically I have two image: image1 shows the piece of paper from the desired view, image2 shows it from an arbitrary view with addition distortion (e.g. bending of the paper and/or lens distortion).
My best try so far was to find features in both images, create an affine transformation matrix from them and apply it to image2. This works to a certain degree but I noticed when overlaying both images that image2 still has some kind of distortion going on in some areas. I assume there is also some lens distortion and/or some distortion due to the bending of the paper within image2. What I saw was that areas with many features fit better than areas with less. Which would make sense since there is only one transformation matrix for the whole image which is biased to areas with many features.

I have added an example image which shows two pages. Please assume that both pages contain identical content and can be feature matched. The left page is the predefined view and the right page shall be transformed. The green and red lines show the distortion due to bending.

But how can I achieve the unbending of the paper and removing the lens distortion (assuming image1 is distortion free)?
Lens calibration(e.g. with a checkerboard) is not an option. I assume that I would require a method which uses many transformation matrices for different areas of the image.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lekAu.jpg)

Comment: you'll need a 3d scanner, or a *lot* of assumptions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.